How can I markup a document for both TeX and HTML?
I have a book that I would like to publish both on Kindle and as a regular printed book. The Kindle version uses HTML as the markup so it has things &nbsp; in it and stuff like that. Obviously that breaks LaTex when it encounters strings like that because I guess "&" is a reserved character.
How can I markup my book in such a way that it can be processed either for HTML/Kindle output and also in TeX/LaTex?
(Note that I use xelatex as my processor so I am forced to use LaTex rather than TeX itself, so I use a really minimalistic {article} class because I prefer to do my own formatting rather than be constrained by a LaTeX document class assumptions, which I have found frustrating.)

your question isn't very clear, any converter from tex to html should be able to handle &nbsp; what do you use (tex4ht for example?) also &nbsp; is just an html entity macro for the character   (U+00A0) which you could use directly without using any & syntax then it will work (like ~) and be a no break space in latex and html without any conversion.

as cfr says you don't have to use latex with xetex. (for a new project I'd use luatex rather than xetex, and use some format other than plain if you don't like latex, eg optex or context)

If you need a  text in several formats, the point is always convert form to simpler to the complex to avoid lossy or wrong conversions. Use markdown as source, then convert it to HTML and  LaTeX versions with pandoc . If strict markdown is not enough, use Quarto markdown that allow include HTML and/or LaTeX.

@Fran Ok, so I use Markdown language for the original document, then convert as needed to LaTex or HTML.

Too long for a comment: The general problem with format conversions is perfectly explained in the Pandoc User's Guide:

Because pandoc’s intermediate [markdown] representation of a document is less expressive than many of the formats it converts between, one should not expect perfect conversions between every format and every other Pandoc attempts to preserve the structural elements of a document, but not formatting details such as margin size. And some document elements, such as complex tables, may not fit into pandoc’s simple document model. While conversions from pandoc’s Markdown to all formats aspire to be perfect, conversions from formats more expressive than pandoc’s Markdown can be expected to be lossy.

This mean that  markdown is the ideal source to not fear the routinary conversion to LaTeX and whatever, but it means to adhere to a simple document structure, that more than a drawback is a good way to follow the wholesome KISS principle (keep it simple, stupid!). A bonus advantage is that markdown is the less obfuscating markup, so it is ideal  to focus in the contents while you write.
Said that, in specific case of LaTeX to HTML,  you can also consider try  more specific converters as htlatex or tex4ht, among others and the same apply in the opposite direction with tools as html2latex or html2tex, but without descend first to the peaceful markdown simplicity, you mileage will vary depending of how baroque and bizarre is your source.
